# Ask for explanation of some notations in Ethereum opcodes

Tags: ethereumjs

I am going to implement EVM for my own project, while reading yellow paper, I can not understand some notations, can anybody help me to clarify them:

[image]

what is µ_i in the picture above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the second paragraph of section 3 in the paper:

> The two sets of highly structured, ‘top-level’, state values, are
>   denoted with bold lowercase Greek letters. They fall into those of
>   world-state, which are denoted *σ* (or a variant thereupon) and those of
>   machine-state, ***µ***.

So *µ* represents the state inside the EVM. *µ'* represents the new EVM state, after some transition has been applied. For example:

> (133) *µ*'<sub>s</sub> ≡ *µ*<sub>s</sub> + ∆

Further in section 3:

> Square brackets are used to index into and reference individual
>   components or subsequences of sequences, e.g. *µ<sub>s</sub>*[0] denotes the first
>   item on the machine’s stack. For subsequences, ellipses are used to
>   specify the intended range, to include elements at both limits, e.g.
>   *µ<sub>m</sub>*[0..31] denotes the first 32 items of the machine’s memory

Finally, your *i* query (section 222):

> *µ*'<sub>i</sub> is defined as this new maximum number of words of active memory;

Meaning *µ*<sub>i</sub> was the number of words of active memory before any change was made in the EVM.